# loading Multiple URLS using fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am attempting to fetch multiple URLs in React using the `Promise.all()` method:

```
const urls = [
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=2",
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=3",
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=4"
];

Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))).then(
  members => {
    console.log(members);
    this.setState({
      nearbymems: members.members
    });
  }
);
```

The console.log is returning all of the URLs together but it is not displaying them on my map application.
I have declared an empty array in my state : `nearbymems: []`

I will also post my render() function for displaying the data as markers in leaflet:

```
{this.state.nearbymems.map(members => (
  <Marker
    position={[members.location.latitude, members.location.longitude]}
    icon={myIcon1}
  >
    <Popup>
      <h1 className="lead">{members.name} </h1>

      <PopupModal initialModalState={true} />
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
))}
```

Thank you.

**edit:**

Output of array:

```
 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 0:
   format:"json"
   latlon:"53,-6"
   members: Array(50)
   0:
      bio:" "
      date:""
      id:44967
      location:
         {latitude: "53.31138992", longitude: "-6.24345493"}
      name: "______"
      url:"https://thesession.org/members/___"
 __proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(members);`? because members will an array.

Comment: Why `nearbymems: members.members`? if `members` is an array, `members.members` is `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe you want to add an additional `.then(res => res.members)` to each promise, since `members.members` will be `undefined`?

Comment: @MayankShukla I have posted the output above.

Comment: @LorenzHenk That was the format for which I was fetching singular URLs. What would be the correct method then?

Comment: @Tholle thanks for your response. I am unsure as to what way to format what you are saying. I have attempted to put a .then() after assigning `Nearbymems: members.members` and it doesn't read .then .

Comment: Judging by the array in your image, you should just have to write `this.setState({ nearbymems: members });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the `members` array from each `fetch` response, and then concatenate these arrays into one before you put it as `nearbymems` in state.

```
Promise.all(
  urls.map(url =>
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => res.members)
  )
).then(members => {
  this.setState({
    nearbymems: [].concat(...members)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` returns an array with each item containing the resolved value of its respective promise. Therefore you cannot simply access `members` from the result of `Promise.all`. Instead you must merge all the values together to get one large array of each promise's `members` value.

This will return all members from each request into a single flattened array.

```
const urls = [
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=2",
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=3",
  "https://thesession.org/members/nearby?latlon=53,-6&radius=1000&format=json&perpage=50&page=4"
];
const requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
const toMembers = responses => responses.map(response => response.members);

Promise.all(requests).then(toMembers).then(members => console.log(members.flat()));
```